# Porting an Apache licensed library from Java to C#, do I need to update the licensing to protect myself?

Tags: licensing, apache-license, porting

I'm porting the [ESRI geometry-api-java](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/) library to C#. They have placed the library under [the Apache License](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/blob/master/license.txt). They also mention it in the README.md.

They have a small bit of licensing info in the header of each [source file](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/esri/core/geometry/AttributeStreamBase.java). Do I have to replace that header with my own Apache 2.0 License disclaimer? Or do I just leave theirs in place? Or do I append my own disclaimer below theirs?

Basically, I want to make this ported version of the library publicly available, but I don't want to get screwed by some lawyer.

Comment: How much are you changing during your “porting” efforts? If it essentially amounts to a re-write in another language where you only try to model the original API, then it is your own work.

Comment: @5gon12eder, I'm using the [Sharpen](https://github.com/mono/sharpen) tool in order to do an initial port. At that point it has thousands of errors. Then I have a about 500 lines of python script that takes it the rest of the way there (missing a few classes). It is almost completely the same library as the original.

Comment: Okay, if you use a tool to do a more or less “mechanical” transformation, then it is a derivative work still covered by the copyright of the original work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be found right in the license text (emphasis mine).

> 4. Redistribution. **You may reproduce and distribute copies of the
>      Work or Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without
>      modifications**, and in Source or Object form, provided that You
>      meet the following conditions:
>
>    (a) You must give any other recipients of the Work or
>         Derivative Works a copy of this License; and
>
>    (b) **You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices
>         stating that You changed the files**; and
>
>    (c) **You must retain**, in the Source form of any Derivative Works
>         that You distribute, **all copyright, patent, trademark, and
>         attribution notices** from the Source form of the Work,
>         excluding those notices that do not pertain to any part of
>         the Derivative Works; and
>
>    (d) If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its
>         distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must
>         include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained
>         within such NOTICE file, excluding those notices that do not
>         pertain to any part of the Derivative Works, in at least one
>         of the following places: within a NOTICE text file distributed
>         as part of the Derivative Works; within the Source form or
>         documentation, if provided along with the Derivative Works; or,
>         within a display generated by the Derivative Works, if and
>         wherever such third-party notices normally appear. The contents
>         of the NOTICE file are for informational purposes only and
>         do not modify the License. You may add Your own attribution
>         notices within Derivative Works that You distribute, alongside
>         or as an addendum to the NOTICE text from the Work, provided
>         that such additional attribution notices cannot be construed
>         as modifying the License.
>
>    **You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications** and
>      may provide additional or different license terms and conditions
>      for use, reproduction, or distribution of Your modifications, or
>      for any such Derivative Works as a whole, provided Your use,
>      reproduction, and distribution of the Work otherwise complies with
>      the conditions stated in this License.

So, in short, yes, you *must* keep their original copyright notice *and* add a notice that you edited the file. In addition, you *may* add your own copyright notice if you want.  (I recommend you do.)